# how to install the pod file in my Xcode project

Tags: terminal, cocoapods

As i am trying to integrate the pod file in my project but whenever i trying to install the pod file in my project i am getting the following error like **[!] No Xcode project found, please specify one**

```
PSSHSRDT047:~ muruganandamc$                                                                                       /Users/muruganandamc/Desktop/cardio/cardio.xcodeproj
-bash: /Users/muruganandamc/Desktop/cardio/cardio.xcodeproj: is a directory
PSSHSRDT047:~ muruganandamc$ pod init
[!] No Xcode project found, please specify one
PSSHSRDT047:~ muruganandamc$
```

can anyone please suggest me how to solve this error?

Comment: You need to be in the root directory of your project.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be in the root directory of your project. Currently you are in your user's folder ... `~`.

Do this...

```
cd ~/Desktop/cardio
```

then...

```
pod init
```

That should run for you.